# two thousands five hundreds dollars vs two thousand five hundred dollars

Tags: numbers

Among 'two thousands five hundreds dollars' and 'two thousand five hundred dollars.', which is the right one?

should I put 's' at the end of thousand and hundred?

Answer (score 7):

You don't use plurals with specific numbers (it's redundant), so "two thousand five hundred" is correct.

On the other hand (as pointed out by stangdon), they are used with general numbers: "dozens of times", "hundreds of years", and so on.

**EDIT** Similarly, you do use plurals with fractions, so .02 is "two hundredth**s**", and 3/4 is "three fourths".

Comment: You're right, but a minor clarification: we don't use plurals with *specific* numbers like "three hundred" or "four thousand".  We do use them when we use numbers as groups, like "hundreds of years" or "thousands of people", or even "ten hundreds make a thousand."